# Yii NestedSetBehavior Memory usage

Tags: php, memory-management, yii, model

I use NestedSetBehavior model extension in my project for using db table as a tree.

I wroute example:

```
    $model = SiteMap()->findAll();
    $log .= $this->debug_memory('used')."<br>";
    $ancestors = null;
    foreach ($model as $item) {
        $ancestors = $item->ancestors()->findAll();
    }
    $log .= $this->debug_memory('used')."<br>";
    echo $log;
```

(debug_memory source just return friendly memory_get_usage(), $model has 50 items)

The result is:

```
used: 10525440
used: 15892712
```

After simple calculation - memory usage increased on 5,24 Mb.

But i must use $item->ancestors()->findAll(); many times in cycle, so my memory increased on 138 Mb. And i get @out of memory error".

I try use unset():

```
    $model = SiteMap()->findAll();
    $log .= $this->debug_memory('used')."<br>";
    $ancestors = null;
    foreach ($model as $item) {
       $ancestors= $item->ancestors()->findAll();
    }
    $ancestors = null;
    unset($ancestors);
    $log .= $this->debug_memory('used')."<br>";
    echo $log;
```

But i steel get result:

```
used: 10525984
used: 15893320
```

Behavior ancestors function source is:

```
public function ancestors($depth=null)
{
    $owner=$this->getOwner();
    $db=$owner->getDbConnection();
    $criteria=$owner->getDbCriteria();
    $alias=$db->quoteColumnName($owner->getTableAlias());

    $criteria->mergeWith(array(
        'condition'=>$alias.'.'.$db->quoteColumnName($this->leftAttribute).'<'.$owner->{$this->leftAttribute}.
            ' AND '.$alias.'.'.$db->quoteColumnName($this->rightAttribute).'>'.$owner->{$this->rightAttribute},
        'order'=>$alias.'.'.$db->quoteColumnName($this->leftAttribute),
    ));

    if($depth!==null)
        $criteria->addCondition($alias.'.'.$db->quoteColumnName($this->levelAttribute).'>='.($owner->{$this->levelAttribute}-$depth));

    if($this->hasManyRoots)
    {
        $criteria->addCondition($alias.'.'.$db->quoteColumnName($this->rootAttribute).'='.CDbCriteria::PARAM_PREFIX.CDbCriteria::$paramCount);
        $criteria->params[CDbCriteria::PARAM_PREFIX.CDbCriteria::$paramCount++]=$owner->{$this->rootAttribute};
    }

    return $owner;
}
```

So, my questions is, why this function use so many memory and why when i unset variable memory is not cleaning?

Comment: Do you have an index on your "ancestors" table referencing the "item" table PK?

Comment: Tree placed in single table, the table have this important rows:  id | root | lft | rgt | level, id - it is auto-increment primary key, root - id from element parents root, level - deeps in tree, lft and rgt fields which help to know which element is to the left and to the right of any given element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment out the logging in your `protected/config/main.php` file. (Or wherever you define your configuration settings.)

What you are seeing is likely a result of all the logs being written on each Active Record call, which would explain why unsetting the object doesn't release memory: the memory used isn't in the model, it's in the log.

Try that and report results.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

It's always good to disable the logs (as @willem-renzema already stated) to prevent it from using memory (especially when you're testing for leaks).

However you should call **`detachBehaviors()`** on each ancestor in your example code to stop it from leaking memory. It's good conduct to do this for every object instance with attached behaviors before using `unset` on it to prevent memory leaks from happening. Even when you're not explicitly "unsetting" the object (eg. your variables are moving out of scope).

*See https://github.com/yiiext/nested-set-behavior/issues/25 for more info about this issue in NestedSetBehavior.*

*Also see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1329#issuecomment-18729026 for a more general discussion on memory leaks and circular references in PHP and Yii.*

---

### Note

You could be tempted to use the a destructor (`__destruct()`) to handle the detaching of behaviors for you. **But in this specific case that won't work** because of the [destructor rule mentioned here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#84911).

> "Objects will only free their resources and trigger their
> `__destruct()` method when *all* references are unset. Even when they
> are *in* the object... sigh!" - (nox at oreigon dot de, 2009).

This rule won't be satisfied by just using `unset` on an "ancestor" because the NestedSetBehavior still has a reference to the "ancestor" instance stored in a static array called: `$_cached`. This reference will only be cleared by destroying the NestedSetBehavior instance itself, which will happen of you call `detachBehaviors()` on the "owner" object of the behavior.